# Why does gravity decelerate fast particles?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity

Karl Popper writes:

> [General relativity] entails the astonishing result that any physical particle (photons included) which approaches the centre of a gravitational field with a velocity exceeding six-tenths of the velocity of light is not accelerated by the gravitational field, as in Newton's theory, but decelerated – that is, not attracted by a heavy body, but repelled.<sup>51</sup>

– Popper, Karl. The Myth of the Framework (p. 21). Taylor and Francis. Kindle Edition.

(Source auto-generated by Kindle.)

In the corresponding footnote, he writes:

> More precisely, a body falling from infinity with a velocity *v* > *c*/3<sup>1/2</sup> towards the centre of a gravitational field will be constantly decelerated in approaching this centre.

It sounds a bit like wind resistance but without the wind.

Can somebody please explain why gravity decelerates such sufficiently fast particles?

Comment: I have no idea what Popper means by “acceleration”. It isn’t the standard meaning in GR, where particles moving under only gravity on geodesics have zero acceleration.

Comment: He is talking about the shapirodelayed velocity, the local velocity relative to a stationary oberver at the place does increase up to the speed of light.

Answer (score 4):

This is an artifact of the choice of coordinate system and refers strictly to coordinate acceleration. There is no proper acceleration (what an accelerometer measures) in either direction for any velocity in free fall, and of course as the energy of configuration of the system decreases, the kinetic energy of the system for any given reference frame must increase.

You can find a detailed discussion and derivation of critical velocity here: see [arXiv:gr-qc/0310020](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0310020)

Comment: “*the energy of configuration of the system decreases”* - How do you define this energy? - “*the kinetic energy of the system for any given reference frame must increase*” - How do you define this energy as well? Can you please provide  both definitions in the Schwarzschild coordinates?